# I moved a file in an other directory but Pycharm sees it as if it still was in previous one

Tags: pycharm

I have a Python project which was structured as follows:

```
root
 |__gui
     |__homepage.py
     |__ window.py
 |_prolog
     |_queries.py
```

I moved the file homepage.py into the root directory. I fixed the imports but now I can't run the file because I get an error on the paths which I shouldn't get. Therefore I wrote these two lines in the file homepage.py to see what the file sees.

```
import os
print(os.listdir('.'))
```

The expected output would be:

```
'gui' 'prolog'
```

Instead I get:

```
window.py
```

Meaning that for some reason the file still is still seen as if it was never moved. I don't know why this is happening, maybe Pycharm is caching some information about the previous structure, which should be updated. The problem is, I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is expected, it is just your assumption to be wrong.

The `'.'` points to the *current working directory*, which it is independent to the location of your `homepage.py` file. check on your run configuration where you put the working directory.

PyCharm just selects the working directory from configuration and call your `/<full-path>/homepage.py`, so the working directory is independent to the main script file.

Note: if you want to known the location of main file (which sometime we need), you should use `sys.argv[0]`.